# Unable to get data from content in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have 2 HTML files and 2 js files.

In App.html I want to include login.html and need to fetch the data from login.html and need to use in in App.

**App.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>    
        <script type="text/javascript" src='js/jquery.js'></script>        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>    
        <script type="text/javascript" src='js/jquery.js'></script>
    </head>     
    <body>      
    <div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="userid" id="luserid" ><strong>UserId : </strong></label>
            <input type="text" name="userid" id="userid" value="" class="logon" placeholder="Username" required/>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="password" id="lpassword"><strong>Password :</strong></label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="logon" value="" placeholder="Password" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-body">
            <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">                            
                    <div class="ui-block-a"><a data-role="button" id="loginbtn" data-theme="b">Login</a></div>                          
            </fieldset>
        </div>              
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#content').load('login.html'); 
  });
```

**login.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var userid= $("#userid").val();
    var upassword= $("#password").val();
    alert(userid);
    alert(upassword);               
});
```

Please help me out on this.

**Note:**  I do not want to include the login.js in the Login.html.

Answer (score 1):

You should check for the user and password on the `submit` event, i.e:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
  var userid= $("#userid").val();
  var upassword= $("#password").val();
  alert(userid);
  alert(upassword); 
});
```

You also need to wrap your code inside a `<form>`:

```
<form>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    ...
    </div>    
</form>
```

Comment: $("form").submit(function(e).. )}; this function should be in side the $(document).ready(function(){ ..}); or its out side that. because i am unable to get the data....

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#content').load('login.html', function() {
        var userid= $('#content').find("#userid").val();
        var upassword= $('#content').find("#password").val();
        alert(userid);
        alert(upassword); 
    }); 
});
```

This will make sure that the content of `login.html` has been loaded successfully.
If so, you can fetch the values of `#userid` and `#password`.

Since these were not created when the DOM was created, you cannot access their values directly through `$('#userid')` and `$('#password')` and you may have to use the method `find()` instead.

**PS:** I thougth this link might interest you: [Calling function after .load (Jquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899066/calling-function-after-load-jquery)

Hope this helps.

Comment: As per my understand app.js will take care about data but i want to pass it to login.js.  First i want to load the login.html in app.html and after user will provide the data in the text fields and user click on login button, login.js script will fetch the data and pass it for authentication.

Comment: Hey mate! I understood what you want. As you know, my solution is based on the fact that the functions of `login.js` should be called / defined inside your `app.js`. Is this a problem for you? Do you really need to sepate the functions? Check this link, I think that might interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899066/calling-function-after-load-jquery