# How to play <audio> html AFTER a loading screen?

Tags: jquery, audio, loading, autoplay

I have a loading screen that masks the body while all the files are loading:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.onload = function() {
  $('body').addClass('loaded')
  };
});
```

**I would like my audio file to autoplay AFTER the loading screen is gone** (not 'onload' but *after*).
Any ideas ?
Thank you for your help
Here is what I added so far, thanks to your help, but it still does not work:

```
$(function(){
  $('a.pageFetcher').click(function(){
  $('#main').load($(this).attr('rel'), function() {
  $('audio').get(0).play();
  });
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you include `<audio>` html at Question?

Comment: How are you starting and ending the loading screen?

Comment: the loading screen is taken from here:
https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/css3-preloader-transition/
except that I use onload instead of a timer

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9899089/5049472

Comment: yes it helps! thank you!
I am a beginner to jquery, what am I supposed to replace #main and rel with ?